# Setting an object value from an EditText field in android

Tags: java, android, object, android-edittext

As part of a group project, we are expected to use an object class in our app. I have created a class called User and a constructor which sets the user Name.

In order to get the userName, I have used an EditText field. However, I am now stuck on how to pass the value from the editText to the parameters in the object class. Could any of you provide any assistance please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edittext_id_set_in_xml_layout);
String userName = yourEditText.getText().toString();
YourClass yourClassObj = new YourClass(userName);
```

Answer (score 0):

String str = editText.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

You can call your constructor inside some button as

```
Constructor(Edittextname.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to setup your object with a constructor and getter and setter methods, here's a quick example:

```
public class User {

    private String username;

    //Constructor
    public User(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    //Set username after instantiate
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
}
```

Back in your activity or fragment, you would then do something like this to setup your object with a value from the editText:

```
//Note this is a reference to the edittext object, not the text contents.
EditText myedittext = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.theedittext);

//create user object
User myuser = new User();
//Set username from text inside edittext
myuser.setUsername(myedittext.getText().toString());
```

OR, you can use your constructor as so:

```
User myuser = new User(myedittext.getText().toString());
```

This is a simple example, you should check for nulls and do some other validation, but hopefully this answers your question.
Using getters and setters gives you a bit more freedom to manipulate the object after instantiation.

Hope that makes sense. Best of luck.